# Issue in locating web element selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

I am unable to locate a web element on a website, The web elements of the website are dynamic and the elements which i am trying to locate have very similar attributes to that of others with just small differences like changes in integers. These integers also change when i refresh the page so i am unable to locate can someone help?

I tried following but there maybe mistakes in syntaxes:

1. With contains text = `WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located( (By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Type here...')]") ))`
2. Absolute Xpath and Rel Xpath(these changes)
3. Contains sibling, contains parents but the parent and sibling elements are also unable to locate

here is the html of the element `<div contenteditable="true" class="cke_textarea_inline cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr placeholder cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor15" title="Rich Text Editor, editor15" aria-describedby="cke_849" style="position: relative;" xpath="1">enter question here</div>`

Comment: Add the html please

Comment: <div contenteditable="true" class="cke_textarea_inline cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr placeholder cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor15" title="Rich Text Editor, editor15" aria-describedby="cke_849" style="position: relative;" xpath="1">enter question here</div>

Comment: @SelectorsHub-TheXPathTool So no space?

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces being added () which some time cause issue, please deleting that space. Also if you can share html then we might be able to help. `WebDriverWait(browser,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Type here...')]")))`

I removing space doesn't work then you can try below xpath-

```
//div[text()='enter question here'][contains(@aria-label,'Rich Text Editor')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are really no attributes you would consider reliable, you can access the element by the text inside of it. I'd recommend two things: Don't do this unless you find no other choice, and don't just use //div, add as much XPATH info to the path as you can.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="enter question here"]')
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),"enter question")]')
```